# Traversing or querying $scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a nested structure with directives and controllers, and from the leaf of this structure I have to access a scope property of the root controller. I'm doing it in this way:

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.property.value.push({ name: "Diego" });
```

but it's ugly and unreliable. I wonder if there's a better way to do it, maybe querying the scope? I noticed that every $scope has an ID, may it be used to retrieve the scope without traversing the whole structure? Thanks.

Comment: You logic should not require you to do this. You need to rethink you logic and try solution mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is built around the idea of dependency injection. As such, querying for data outside of your scope is discouraged.

You have several options:

- If you need to access the `$rootScope`, you can simply ask AngularJS to inject it.

For example, if you use a controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($rootScope) {
  // AngularJS will recognize the parameter and populate it
  $rootScope.property.value.push({name: 'Diego'});
});
```

- If you need access to a controller, you can use a directive controller ([short example I made for a talk](https://github.com/lperrin/talk-angularjs-directives/tree/master/4_select)).

For example, you could attach a directive controller to the body and share it with any directive in children:

```
myApp.directive('body', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    controller: function () {
      this.hello = function () { … };
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    require: '^body',

    link: function (scope, element, attr, bodyCtrl) {
      bodyCtrl.hello();
    }
  };
});
```

- Finally, you can also make a singleton service and require it whevener you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the help of $broadcast and $on. See [the Scope docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

In the directive you would do something like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('directiveName.message', {name: 'Diego'});
```

And in the controller you would listen for the events like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('directiveName.message', function(message) {
    console.log(message.name);
});
```

Comment: I thought about this kind of solution but I'm not so sure it's "beautiful" to broadcast messages when I already know who has the function I need.